# Django 1.8 DateTimeInput storing as UnixTimestamp

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, datetimepicker

I have a problem with DateTimeInput fields in Django 1.8.

The following form is used:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Additional init function for changing field behavior

    """
    super(UpdateMaintenanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    self.fields['description'] = forms.CharField(
        required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    self.fields['active_since'] = forms.DateTimeField(
        input_formats=['%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'], widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    self.fields['active_till'] = forms.DateTimeField(
        input_formats=['%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'], widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    self.initial['active_since'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(self.initial['active_since']).strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
    self.initial['active_till'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(self.initial['active_till']).strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
```

I'm storing dates as unix timestamps in the database.
When adding a date I got the error message 'Enter valid Date/Time'. Stepping into the Debugger I found that the Error raises from the to_python method defined for IntegerFields. The problem is very clear to me, I can not add a datetime object to an integer field. But I do not want storing the dates as datetimes into the database. Therefore I need to modify the to_python method to convert a datetime object into a unix timestamp. 
What would be the best way to do this? Write a custom field for my model or is there a way manipulating the widget using an own to_python method?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by subclassing models.Integerfield and adding own to_python conversion:

class UnixDateTime(models.IntegerField):

```
def to_python(self, value):

    if value is None:
        return value
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value
    if isinstance(value, datetime):
        return mktime(value.timetuple())
    else:
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['invalid'], code='invalid', params={'value': value},
        )
```